# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML - How to Hide Column with HTML?

Tags: html, pdf, hide, netsuite, suitescript

I would like to hide the **entire** column "Unit Price" if "Item A" with Internal ID '112' is present at all on an invoice. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my Column "Unit Price":

```
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post your existing code and clarify what you're asking.  Do you want to hide the actual column, like don't show unit price for *any* items if 'Item A' is on the transaction? Or are you 'hiding' the "unit price" for only 'Item A'?

Comment: I have edited my original post.

Comment: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic idea, code is not tested..

Add this in your template before the `<#list record.item as item>` logic:

```
<#assign hideUnitPrice = false>
<#list record.item as item>
    <#if item.internalid == 112>
        <#assign hideUnitPrice = true>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

And change your unit price column code to:

```
<#if hideUnitPrice == false>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
</#if>
```

You would probably also want to wrap the column header in a similar conditional.

Comment: Is this what the first part should look like? `<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items --><#assign hideUnitPrice = false><#list record.item as item><#if item.internalid == '112'><#assign hideUnitPrice = true></#if></#list><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>` This does not work for me

Comment: @bluejay92 That is the general idea. What error are you getting?

Comment: I believe this should work but it still shows the Unit Price column. I am no longer receiving an error, it just still appears. However, I have figured out a workaround. Thank you!